# Mysql SELECT multiple columns or one column and then display results with php. Which option better for performance

Tags: php, mysql

Html many (~30) check-boxes like

```
<input name="heated_seats" value="1" id="heated_seats" type="checkbox">
<input name="electric_windows" value="1" id="electric_windows" type="checkbox">
<input name="cruise_control" value="1" id="cruise_control" type="checkbox">
```

User may check any of them (may check all, may check nothing).

Thinking about performance. Which option would be faster and use less resources?

**Option 1**

mysql

```
HeatedSeats | ElectricWindows | CruiseControl
----------------------------------------------
   1        |     1           |   0
   1        |     0           |   0
   0        |     0           |   0
```

Query like `SELECT HeatedSeats, ElectricWindows, CruiseControl .....`

Php like `if( HeatedSeats == 1 ){ echo 'HeatedSeats'; }` Many `if`

**Option 2**

mysql

```
OneColumnWithPossiblyLongVarcharOrText
----------------------------------------------
Heated seats, Electric windows, ''
Heated seats, '', ''
'', '', ''
```

Query like `SELECT OneColumnWithPossiblyLongVarcharOrText .....`

Php like

```
 $arr = explode( ',' OneColumnWithPossiblyLongVarcharOrText )
 foreach( $arr as $k => $v ){
 if( strlen($v) > 0 ){ echo $v; }
 }
```

For example many visitors do the same select on different rows.

Which option takes less time and uses less resources?

Or may be there some better option?

Comment: 1. Never ever store delimited values in the relational database! 2. Premature optimization is the root of all evil.

Comment: From comment understand that better would be Option 1?

Comment: Let me put it this way - option 2 is not an option at all. Now there are several ways how to design a schema to store entity (I assume car in your case) properties e.g. it might be a bunch of columns like you showed in option 1 or it might be a pivot table `car_property`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Option 1 will be better for your scenario and it will take less time if many visitors do the same select on different rows.

**With Option 1**

```
 You have to query and check for multiple conditions which is not good but will help you in future.
 On insert you have to insert multiple checkbox value to multipel columns.
```

**With Option 2**

```
You have to query and with some exploding and looping you can easily check which option is checked.
On insert you need to just insert single column value. 
But on update it is hard to maintain delimeter values
```